# Javascript this keyword not functioning within a function referenced by addEventListener

Tags: javascript, scope, this, addeventlistener

I'm writing a minesweeper game using HTML and Javascript which allows the user to input how big the grid is and how many mines, and the board is generated when a button is pressed. The board consists of a table with rows and cells generated in Javascript with a couple loops. Inside a loop is an addEventListener statement which is supposed to add the function to be called when a cell is clicked on.

My problem is that I'm not sure how to pass each individual cell object into the function so I can play around with it. I've been trying to use

```
this.setAttribute(...)
```

but I'm getting an error which tells me this.setAttribute is not a function. I know that "this" is probably referring to global scope, but I'm not sure how to solve my problem then, and I've had trouble finding a solution elsewhere. Here's the relevant code:

```
function createGame(){
    size= document.getElementById("boardSize").value;
    //other stuff
    var table= document.createElement("table");
    table.id= "gameBoard";
    document.body.appendChild(table);
    for(var r= 1; r <= size; r++){
        var row= document.createElement("tr");
        row.setAttribute("id", "r" + r.toString(10));
        document.getElementById("gameBoard").appendChild(row);
        for(var c= 1; c <= size; c++){
            var cell= document.createElement("td");
            cell.setAttribute("id", "r" + r.toString(10) + "c" + c.toString(10));
            cell.setAttribute("class", "uClear");
            cell.innerHTML= "?";                                           
            document.getElementById("r" + r.toString(10)).appendChild(cell);
            cell.addEventListener("click", clickClear);
        }
    }
    //other stuff
}
//the following is in global scope
function clickClear(){
    this.setAttribute("class", "kClear");   //this is undefined
    //other stuff
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: It works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/nwtb2ysq/2/

Comment: The `this` context of an EventListener *(that is not in an Arrow function)* is the Element, which would be `cell` or the `<td>` Element you are creating at each step of the loop, so that's not the issue.

Comment: Maybe the element isn't properly loaded when the function is called?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this,by passing the element reference inside the variable:

```
    size= document.getElementById("boardSize").value;
    //other stuff
    var table= document.createElement("table");
    table.id= "gameBoard";
    document.body.appendChild(table);
    for(var r= 1; r <= size; r++){
        var row= document.createElement("tr");
        row.setAttribute("id", "r" + r.toString(10));
        document.getElementById("gameBoard").appendChild(row);
        for(var c= 1; c <= size; c++){
            var cell= document.createElement("td");
            cell.setAttribute("id", "r" + r.toString(10) + "c" + c.toString(10));
            cell.setAttribute("class", "uClear");
            cell.innerHTML= "?";                                           
            document.getElementById("r" + r.toString(10)).appendChild(cell);
            cell.addEventListener("click",() => clickClear(cell)); // arrow function
        }
    }
    //other stuff
}
//the following is in global scope
function clickClear(element){
    element.setAttribute("class", "kClear");   // pass the element reference instead
    //other stuff
}
```

Also, you might want to check my blog about creating a PWA minesweeper app using Web components:
https://onecompileman.com/blogs/10

Comment: Hmm. This doesn't solve the problem, although I'm sure it should work. I'm starting to think there's something wrong earlier, with my organization or waiting until something loads